# Create a square polygon (random oriented) from midpoints in Python

Tags: python, function, computational-geometry

I have a midpoint (x,y) and i need to create a square polygon with random orientation using a 2D (random) planar rotation.

```
def get_square_plot(x, y, side):
    return [(x-(side/2), y+(side/2)), (x+(side/2), y+(side/2)), (x+(side/2), y-(side/2)), (x-(side/2), y-(side/2))]
```

This function creates the vertices of a square polygon without a specific orientation. I wish to improve this function adding the possibility to rotation randomly these vertices (and with a specific angle if is possible)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, this should be able to do what you want:

```
from math import sin, cos, radians

def rotated_square(cx, cy, size, degrees=0):
    """ Calculate coordinates of a rotated square centered at 'cx, cy'
        given its 'size' and rotation by 'degrees' about its center.
    """
    h = size/2
    l, r, b, t = cx-h, cx+h, cy-h, cy+h
    a = radians(degrees)
    cosa, sina = cos(a), sin(a)
    pts = [(l, b), (l, t), (r, t), (r, b)]
    return [(( (x-cx)*cosa + (y-cy)*sina) + cx,
             (-(x-cx)*sina + (y-cy)*cosa) + cy) for x, y in pts]

print rotated_square(50, 50, 100)
```

Output:

```
[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 100.0), (100.0, 100.0), (100.0, 0.0)]
```

Note that in the general case, the resulting coordinates *won't* be integers.

What this does effectively is first translate each coordinate to the origin by subtracting cx,cy from it, rotates that by the angle, and then un-translates it back by the same amount. This is necessary to compensate for the fact that rotation formulas usually are relative to origin of a coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

having determined the four corner coordinates, you can rotate them relative to the origin (or midpoint) using a simple 2D Matrix Rotation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29 (search for 2D rotation equation)

```
x' = x cos(theta) - y sin(theta)
y' = x sin(theta) + y cos(theta)
```

You can use the built-in Python Math library for the cos/sin functions: http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html  section 9.2.3

```
Math.cos(theta)
Math.sin(theta)
```

I hope this is of some use!