# How to animate the movement and the rotation of multiple objects?

Tags: python, blender

I have a drone composed of multiple objects. The problem is that when I rotate the drone and move it to some other point it looses its shape (torn to pieces), every part of the drone disconnects from the main body. How can I rotate and move the drone without loosing its shape?

I have tried to make the body of the drone the parent of all the pieces. It's working when I only rotate or move the body.
[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWc16.png)

```
import math
import bpy
import mathutils
import subprocess as sp
from math import sqrt, degrees, acos, pow

sp.call('cls', shell=True)

drone_objects_names = ['Cube.008', 'Cylinder.007', 'Cube.007', 'Cube.006', 'Sphere.005', 'Sphere.004', 'Cylinder.008',
                       'Sphere.003', 'Cylinder.006', 'Cube.005', 'Cube.004', 'Sphere.002', 'Cylinder.005', 'Sphere.001',
                       'Cylinder.004', 'Sphere', 'Cylinder.003', 'Cube.003', 'Cylinder.002', 'Cylinder.001', 'Cube.002',
                       'Cube.001', 'Cylinder', 'Cube']

X = 10
Y = 10
Z = 5

frame_num = 0
teta = 0

factor = 0.97


def set_keyframe():
    for object_name in drone_objects_names:
        bpy.data.objects[object_name].keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)


def send_drone_to_center():
    move_drone(-bpy.data.objects['Cylinder.003'].location)


def select_drone():
    for object_name in drone_objects_names:
        bpy.data.objects[object_name].select_set(True)


def move_drone(v):
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=v)


def angle_between_z(vc, uc):
    nominator = vc[0] * uc[0] + vc[2] * uc[2]
    denominator = sqrt(pow(vc[0], 2) + pow(vc[2], 2)) * sqrt(pow(uc[0], 2) + pow(uc[2], 2))
    return acos(nominator / denominator)


def angle_between_y(vc, uc):
    nominator = vc[0] * uc[0] + vc[2] * uc[2]
    denominator = sqrt(pow(vc[0], 2) + pow(vc[2], 2)) * sqrt(pow(uc[0], 2) + pow(uc[2], 2))
    return acos(nominator / denominator)


def do_step():
    global factor, teta, frame_num, X, Y, Z
    factor = 0.97

    x_new = X * math.cos(math.radians(teta))
    y_new = Y * math.sin(math.radians(teta))

    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)

    move_drone(-bpy.data.objects['Cylinder.003'].location)
    move_drone((x_new, y_new, Z * factor))

    angle = angle_between_z((x_new, y_new, Z * factor), (X, Y, Z))
    bpy.data.objects['Cylinder.003'].rotate_euler[2] = angle

    set_keyframe()

    frame_num += 3

    X *= factor
    Y *= factor
    Z *= factor
    teta += 10


select_drone()
send_drone_to_center()
move_drone((X, Y, Z))

while math.sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z) > 1:
    do_step()
    e = bpy.data.objects['Cylinder.003'].location
    print(X, Y, e[0], e[2])

bpy.context.scene.frame_end = frame_num
```

I'm expecting to get the drone in the center of the referential without losing its shape...
[drone lose it's shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aoFz.png)

The drone I'm using in this project (if you want to try it...): [drone](https://free3d.com/3d-model/evil-spy-drone-34477.html)

Comment: I'm not familiar with blender, but you might find the explanation of the math involved in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842362/355230) to the question [Rotate line around center point given two vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842090/rotate-line-around-center-point-given-two-vertices) helpful since the same concepts apply to 3D geometry.

Comment: In your script `rotate_euler` should be `rotation_euler`. Also you are only keyframing the location, you may also want to keyframe the rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is applying the same movement to every part of the drone. As a child, the objects location is relative to the parent object, by changing the location of a child it is being moved away from the parent, which is also being moved.

Either remove the parenting, or only animate the parent object.