# How do I change the angle of a rectangle on the tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas

I am trying to draw a cartoon frog on `Canvas`, on Python 3.
This is my code for the leg:

```
RightLeg = c.create_rectangle(600, 600, 700, 400, outline= 'green', fill= 'green')
```

I get my frog body off previous code, but my leg is a vertical leg. What I get:

[image: screenshot of what I get]

However, I want my leg to  be more on a 45degree angle, so I can make it look better. What I want:

[image: screenshot of what I want]

I've tried to add a angle function, but Python does not have one.
I've tried to play around with co-ordinates, but I can't get it.
My project is on a 800x800 grid

Comment: `Canvas` object's don't support rotated rectangles — but you could draw one "manually" via their [`create_polygon()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/create_polygon.html) method.

Comment: P.S. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842362/355230) to a question about rotating polygons describes the math involved.